# ssrs with visible filter

Tags: sql, reporting-services, report

I have the above SSRS Report. I used adventurewoorks2014. Any adventureworks will do. My problem is that I want to filter by month in this example October 2011 so that the corresponding graph will turn yellow and others are still in blue and visible.
In other words, whenever I choose a value from the top the corresponding graph should turn yellow and I can still see other graph but in blue. Any question please let me know. Many thanks in advance

```
    ----Query FROM Adventureworks
SELECT [SalesOrderID]
      ,[OrderDate]
,DATENAME(MONTH,[OrderDate])+' '+DATENAME(YEAR,[OrderDate]) AS MonthYear
FROM [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader]

    enter code here
--------Parameter query
SELECT distinct
DATENAME(MONTH,[OrderDate])+' '+DATENAME(YEAR,[OrderDate]) AS MonthYear
FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[Sales].[SalesOrderHeader]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an expression on the backcolor for the graph which sets to yellow if the corresponding label is the same as the selected parameter and blue if not.

Note that if the parameter is changed then the report will need to be regenerated in order for the colour to change. There is no alternative to this behaviour in SSRS.

Comment: I Have done that, it is not working. i believe it is because they are from two dataset

Comment: "It is not working"!! What happens? Any errors? What is your expression? To which property have you applied your expression? Within your expression have you tried manually setting the color to something random such as Red just to prove you have the correct property?

Comment: I tried this =IIF(Fields!MonthYear.Value=Fields!MonthYear.Value, "MonthData","Yellow","Blue"). but if i set it to other colour. they are change to that colour

Comment: Your IIF statement contains too many parameters.Try IIF(paramater value = data value, "Yellow","Blue")